# Fastboot failed with (data transfer failure (No error))

Tags: fastboot

Sorry for newbie question,

I'm running fastboot on windows and sometimes fastboot returns this error

```
FAILED (data transfer failure (No error))
```

and when it get this error it continue to send this error until I reboot the PC and re-run it again.

```
C:\>fastboot.exe -s tcp:192.168.1.73 flash system_i C:\system.img
target reported max download size of 268435456 bytes
erasing 'system_i'...
OKAY [ 60.543s]
sending sparse 'system_i' 1/2 (262140 KB)...
FAILED (data transfer failure (No error))
finished. total time: 86.195s

C:\>
```

Note: it usually happen on large files, but when it happen, it also fails on all other files including small ones until I reboot the PC.

I have not encounter this problem on Linux, it seems it's specific to Windows version, probably fastboot itself or windows setup. (different fastboot version tried).

I search and did not find any complain for this kind of error!

Note: fastboot downloaded from internet. https://developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:
This problem happen in case that the fastboot is not compatible with software version, e.g. when we want to run a fastboot.exe from Windows and connect to a device that has software has been built with Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change USB port
2. Update USB drivers, Install Intel USB Android driver, uninstall Kies / other USB connecting application.
3. Change USB cable
4. Change PC (you might have problem with your board USB or driver)

Comment: yo @ mudy s, thank you! Changing the USB cable worked for me! I would have never thought of that... It's funny how sometimes fixes are so simple but unexpected.

Comment: Charge USB port and/or USB cable. That worked in my case.